# Query return rows whose sum of column value match given sum

Tags: sql

I have tables with:

```
id   desc   total
1   baskets 25
2   baskets 15
3   baskets 75
4   noodles 10
```

I would like to ask the query with output which the sum of total is 40.

The output would be like:

```
id   desc   total
1   baskets 25
2   baskets 15
```

Comment: But the sum of the total of `baskets` is 115. What happens to the row containing `total = 75`?

Comment: How do you expect to get that output (2 rows only, with no sum)?

Comment: I deleted my original answer as I didn't read the second half more carefully. It appears that he is trying to find any combinations that total 40 and have the same description

Comment: Repeating my comment below (but for the OP this time). "desc" is a reserved word (used in `ORDER BY` clauses to specify direction). Choose better column names

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want, but this may get you started

```
SELECT `desc`, SUM(Total) Total
FROM TableName
GROUP BY `desc`
HAVING SUM(Total) = 40
```

Comment: with that query I get the error that Invalid use of group function

Comment: "desc" is a reserved word and should be quoted as an identifier (depends on RDBMS). Or better yet, choose a saner column name

Comment: `DESC` is a key word, always escape field names (using `) if they match any SQL key word.

Comment: @phil-brown You are correct, however that won't trigger the error "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @Amil Backticks are only used as identifier quotes in MySQL. In Oracle, use double-quotes. Square brackets for SQL Server. Not sure about PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will get you a list of the results you're looking for, but not with your example dataset because nothing in your example dataset can provide a total sum of 40.

```
SELECT id, desc, total 
FROM mytable 
WHERE desc IN (
  SELECT desc 
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY desc 
  HAVING SUM(total) = 40
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Desc,SUM(Total) as SumTotal
from Table
group by desc
having SUM(Total)  > = 40
```

Answer (score 1):

From reading your question, it sounds like you want a query that returns any subset of of sums that represent a certain target value and have the same description.

There is no simple way to do this. This migrates into algorithmic territory.

Assuming I am correct in what you are after, group bys and aggregate functions will not solve your problem. SQL cannot indicate that a query should be performed on subsets of data until it exhaust all possible permutations and finds the Sums that match your requirements.

You will have to intermix an algorithm into your sql ... i.e a stored procedure.

Or simply get all the data from the database that fits the desc then perform your algorithm on it in code.

I recall there was a CS algorithmic class I took where this was a known Problem:

I believe you could just adapt working versions of this algorithm to solve your problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: If this answers your question please feel free to mark it as answered =D

Answer (score 0):

```
select desc 
from (select desc, sum(total) as ct group by desc)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!